# Java Error :" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1"

Tags: java, apache-camel, pgp

I was looking for a script that will enable me to encrypt and decrypt a file using *PGP*. I stumble across this tutorial:

https://dzone.com/articles/pgp-encryption-and-decryption-with-apache-camel

but whenever I run the code I get an `error` :

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> Marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.PGPDataFormat@10e92f8f] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:C:\Users\Regie\keys\IN?noop... because of Data format 'pgp' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath

I'm not sure what jar file I missed. I just can't get solution on how to make the script run, the author does not reply on my question.

PGP Questions : I'm required to follow the following requirements :

- Alogorithm : DSA and Elgamal
  -DSA keypair must have 1024 bits
  -ELG-E Keys 2048 bits

I would really appreciate if you can give me additional information on the Algorithm and i'm keen to understand if it is already implemented in a *PGP* encryption of the script on the link above.

By the way **I'm new to Java.**

Comment: Maybe your input is invalid ( secret key file name)

Comment: @Mohammadreza Panahi I double checked the path and name of the public key and it looks good

Answer (score 0):

You need to have camel-crypto on the classpath. The dzone article does not mention this, it just hints at it in one of the screenshots. If you're using Maven you can add a dependency like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi @James Netherton, I added the camel-crypto as an external jar on the project. but I'm still getting the same error.